# Creating and Extracting a PHP Archive in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, zip, phar

Today I started working on a new project that will convert a .phar to a .zip and a .zip to .phar. How could I do this with Node.js? Yes I understand that this may not be possible but I would like some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by implementing a phar file format reader in javascript.
The PHP manual has [a section about the Phar file formats](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.php).

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of when this was done?